# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.dartundefined_operator

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is the full code but I m getting error in title: `Text(map["title"]),` part of the code

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();


     void _addTask() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("todos")
      .add({"title": _controller.text});

    _controller.text = "";
    }

    Widget _buildList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
     itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final doc = snapshot.docs[index];
      final map = doc.data();
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(map["title"]),
        );
      },
    );
    }

    class TodoListPage extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter task name",
              ),
            )),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Add Task',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed: () {
                _addTask();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("todos").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

            return Expanded(child: _buildList(snapshot.data));
          },
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo List'),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(context),
        );}
     }
```

I want to display the title of the document of the cloud firestore.

Error

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.
```

Comment: Try put final Map map = doc.data()

Comment: Please check the duplicate for the correct solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `itemBuilder`, more specifically in format of the `map` variable not having an expected value so that the title field can be fetched. Since you are not using this `map` variable for anywhere else, nor the `doc` variable, you can scrap the creation of these 2 extra variable and pass the value directly to your `ListTile`, like this:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(snapshot.docs[index].data()["title"]),
    );
},
```