# After updating cloud firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Every thing was working good but when i upgraded my cloud firestore dependecy. I started getting an error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. ". This error is coming in front of all the 4 userData.data()[""],

```
class BaseProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  //instances of firebase

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final CollectionReference postsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts");

  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  //Creating post

  Future addPost(
    
  ) async {
    DocumentSnapshot userData =
        await userCollection.doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get();
    return await postsCollection.doc().set({
      "id": _auth.currentUser.uid,
      "sellername": userData.data()["name"],      //Error
      "sellercontact": userData.data()["phone"],  //Error
      "sellercity": userData.data()["city"],      //Error
      "sellerstate": userData.data()["state"],    //Error
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: try putting a `print` statement to check what that data is. You might have to `jsonDecode` first.

Comment: print(userData.data()); when is print using this i get full json data but when i try to get a particular data it shows error. if i use this dependency it'll not show any error and will work smoothly cloud_firestore 1.0.7. But after upgrading errors are coming print(userData.data()["name"]);

Comment: and if print(userData) it'll give Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(userData.data());

    print(user["name"].toString());   Tried this too still not working

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Starting at `cloud_firestore` Version 2.0.0

The class `DocumentSnapshot` now takes a generic parameter. The declaration:

```
abstract class DocumentSnapshot<T extends Object?> {
```

and therefore it contains an abstract method of type `T`:

```
  T? data();
```

Therefore you need to do the following:

```
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> userData =
        await userCollection.doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get();
    return await postsCollection.doc().set({
      "id": _auth.currentUser.uid,
      "sellername": userData.data()["name"],      
      "sellercontact": userData.data()["phone"],  
      "sellercity": userData.data()["city"],      
      "sellerstate": userData.data()["state"], 
      
    });
```

Now `data()` method will be of type `Map<String,dynamic>` and you can access the data as you normally do using the `[]` operator.

---

#### Another Example:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionPath");
final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>> snapshots = query.snapshots();
```

The above will give the error:

> A value of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.

You get this error because `Query` has the following declaration:

```
abstract class Query<T extends Object?>
```

while `snapshots()` returns the following:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<T>> snapshots({bool includeMetadataChanges = false});
```

Since a type wasn't specified for `Query` and since `T extends Object?`, therefore in the code `snapshots()` will have the following return type `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>` and you will get the above error. So to solve this you have to do:

```
Query<Map<String,dynamic>> query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionPath");
final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>> snapshots = query.snapshots();
```

---

According to the [docs](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/CHANGELOG.md):

> BREAKING REFACTOR: DocumentReference, CollectionReference, Query, DocumentSnapshot, CollectionSnapshot, QuerySnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, Transaction.get, Transaction.set and WriteBatch.set now take an extra generic parameter. (#6015).

Therefore you need to implement the above for all those classes.

Answer (score 16):

in my case I simply had to change `snapshot.data()['parameter']` to `snapshot.get('parameter')`

```
UserModel _userFromFirebaseSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
 return snapshot != null ?
    UserModel(snapshot.id,
      name: snapshot.get('name'),
      profileImageUrl: snapshot.get('profileImageUrl'),
      email: snapshot.get('email'),
    ) : null;
 }
```