# FlutterFire Firestore 2.0.0 migration issues with streaming collections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This code block results in the error below when trying to run my app. The [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration) has me lost on what to change `Map<String, dynamic>? data` to?

```
Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>({
  required String path,
  required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>? data, String documentID) builder,
  Query? Function(Query query)? queryBuilder,
  int Function(T lhs, T rhs)? sort,
}) {
  Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
  if (queryBuilder != null) {
    query = queryBuilder(query)!;
  }
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = query.snapshots();
  return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
    final result = snapshot.docs
        .map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id))
        .where((value) => value != null)
        .toList();
    if (sort != null) {
      result.sort(sort);
    }
    return result;
  });
}
```

> Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
>   .map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id))

**Edit:**

If I update the QuerySnapshot with `final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshots = query.snapshots();` I get the following error now.

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob/67610936#67610936

Comment: @PeterHaddad I looked at that post, but I'm not seeing a fix to my issue with a Stream QuerySnapshot. See my comment below to Victor Eronmosele. How do I get `query.snapshots()` to return a Map?

Comment: the same as I explained in the answer..

Comment: Sorry, if it is in front of my face, I'm not seeing it. If you're willing please provide an answer with code, specific to my use case. Also, note, I just added an Edit to my original post with the updates I've made and the issue I now have.

Comment: Check the duplicate, updated it with your use case. When you try it tell me if everything worked or not, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the object type contained in the QuerySnapshot like shown below:

```dart
    final   Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshots =
          query.snapshots() as Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>;
```

[Migration Guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/#migration)

Comment: This almost gets me there, but `query.snapshots()` has red underline and this error: A value of type `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

If I change to Object this breaks all functions looking for a map. How do I get `query.snapshots()` to return `Map<String, dynamic>>`?

Comment: Hi @Zelf, I've updated the answer with a cast. This should remove the red lines.

Comment: Ah, of course, that would have worked as well.