# Type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' error

Tags: string, flutter, dynamic, hash, hyperlink

I am new to flutter. I am following a tutorial. I am creating a basic chat app. When I type code there is no error, but when I run code there is this error. I don't know what I have done wrong. Going with the tutorial. In the tutorial, the instructor does it without any error.

```
void messagesStream() async {
await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
  for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
    print(message.data());
  }
}}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: null,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            messagesStream();
            // _auth.signOut();
            // Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
    ],
    title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            // ignore: missing_return
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                );
              }
              final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
              List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
              for (var message in messages) {
                final messageText = message.data();
                final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
                  text: messageText,
                );
                messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
                  children: messageBubbles,
                ),
              );
            }),
```

Comment: include your full error message with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore values are in maps, meaning that to access one of its values you need to use a key. Take this as an example:

[image: Database message structure example]

So for example if you want to acces this message data, firestore provides you with a map, as it has multiple values, meaning that you cant just do message.data(), as it will just retrieve the map. So this would be the right code:

```
for (var message in messages) {
            final messageData = message.data();
            final messageText= messageData['text'];

            final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
              text: messageText,
            );
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }
```

You see that to retrieve any fields from de given document data, you make use of [] followed by the name of the field inside. Give it a try, it should now work.

Comment: Thanks, @VoidX. After using the ['text'], it is giving an error that the operator '[]'  isn't defined for the type Object.

Comment: I think this question answer can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob

Comment: Make sure you added those fields with the exact name in the document, otherwise you wont be able to get their data