# Flutter Firestore Operator isn't defined

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm getting this error

> error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [mbpayment] lib\screens\transactionhistory\transaction_history.dart:61)

This is the code

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('transactionHistory').where('SenderEmail', isEqualTo: user.email).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.hasData?snapshot.data!.docs.length:0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('To: ' + snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!['RecipientEmail'].toString()),
                      subtitle: Text('Details: ' + snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!['RecipientReference'].toString()),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      trailing: Text('RM ' + snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!['amount'].toString(), style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
```

I am trying to make a list view for transaction history.

Comment: This error message has come up quite a few times recently, so I recommend having a look at some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+The+operator+%27%5B%5D%27+isn%27t+defined+for+the+type+%27Object%27.

Comment: I didnt find any with the same context as my problem. Do you have any solution? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After updating cloud firestore: The operator '\[\]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '\[\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue stems from the 2.0.0 changes on cloud_firestore. Check [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/) out. If that's it, you have to add the `Map<String, dynamic>>` generic parameter where it's needed.