# Flutter - cloud_firestore 2.5.x- null safety update : query startAfterDocument keep initializing from first document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Since updating my flutter project to :

- null safety
- With cloud_firestore 2.5.x requiring to specify the type
  Map<String, dynamic> for DocumentSnapshot according to
  [After updating cloud firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob)

my query with startAfterDocument keep resending the same results starting from 0.

```
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> queryColl = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(customerId)
    .collection('ledger_transactions')
    .limit(iLimit)
    .orderBy('created_at', descending: true);
    if (lastDoc != null) {
     print('getCustomerLedger lastDoc != null ${lastDoc.id}');
    queryColl.startAfterDocument(
      lastDoc!);
   } 

   QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await queryColl.get();
```

I cannot figure out in the documentation and S.O what has been changed in specs. Doesnt work also with StartAt/StartAtDocument/StartAfter

Comment: Yes Frank it was helpful, was a shame i missed that immutable part... i felt it was working with previous version of Flutter firestore with same code...but really important to keep that point in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are immutable once you construct them. So when you call `startAfterDocument` that returns a **new** query, that you need to assign to `queryColl` again.

Something like:

```
queryColl = queryColl.startAfterDocument(
  lastDoc!);
}
```